WordPress exclude custom post types from search
The following code works in preventing our "Projects" from appearing in the site search results, but it is causing unintended consequences for various filtering on the admin backend. Is there any way to contain the function to only the front end search?
function ss_search_filter( $query ) {

if ( $query->is_admin() ) :
    return $query;
endif;


if ( $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    // set the post type to only post types you want returned.
    $query->set( 'post_type', ['page', 'post', 'product'] );
}


return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ss_search_filter' );


Are you creating this CPT with register_post_type? If so you should be able to just set exclude_from_search to true. If you aren't using that function, you can also manually set it with a hook

I've rolled your edit back. Although it corrects the problem, this causes confusion for future readers.

Thank you for this. I ultimately implemented the solution from your link.

The $query->is_admin() is likely incorrect. Try changing it to is_admin().
Additional note: pre_get_posts is an action, not a filter, so returning variables is incorrect.

Thank you, Caleb. Just using is_admin() appears to have solved the problem. As far as pre_get_posts, removing it throws many PHP errors. Have a great day!

Within the callback ss_search_filter(), change the first return $query; to simply return;, and remove the last return $query;.
